# finding the values of a dictionary created from a gml file

Tags: matplotlib, graph, networkx, data-science, gml

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
G = nx.read_gml('data_sets/karate.gml' , label='id')
nx.degree(G).values()
```

By using the above code , i wanted to find the values of the dictionary of nx.degree(G).

But the terminal is throwing an error as :
'

> **DegreeView' object has no attribute 'values'**

here the output of the statement nx.degree(G) was:

```
 DegreeView({1: 16, 2: 9, 3: 10, 4: 6, 5: 3, 6: 4, 7: 4, 8: 4, 9: 5, 10: 2, 11: 3, 12: 1, 13: 2, 14: 5, 15: 2, 16: 2, 17: 2, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 3, 21: 2, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 5, 25: 3, 26: 3, 27: 2, 28: 4, 29: 3, 30: 4, 31: 4, 32: 6, 33: 12, 34: 17})
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the output, the return value of `nx.degree` is a `DegreeView` object. You can convert it into a `dictionary` with `dict()`. For your examples it would be:

```
G = nx.read_gml('data_sets/karate.gml' , label='id')
print(dict(nx.degree(G)).values())
```